# Android: MyExpandableAdapter - CRASHES when trying to expand the listview only for one section at time

Tags: android, crash, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, setcontentview

As another part of my problem, in MyExpandableAdapter::OnGroupExpanded, **collapsegroup** couldn't be called because the expandablelistview couldn't be referenced.

Comment: While providing help in form of a self-answered question is a laudable pursuit, I see problems with this one: the title - little need to repeat the first tag, and what is `MyExpandableAdapter`? The body: How would a reader know what `another part of my problem` is referring to? If she did, would it help understanding this question/add value to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've just got a crash again and again when tried to expand only 1 section at time. Finally, after lots of hours, I've succeeded and I'll unite solutions I found.

For solving it, we need to access the expandableListView in ExpandableAdapter.

**1.**
in our ExpandableAdapter, we set our activity member.

```
public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

**2.**
onGroupExpanded method:

```
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    if (previousExpandedParentIndex != -1 && previousExpandedParentIndex != groupPosition) {
        ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        elv.collapseGroup(previousExpandedParentIndex);
    }
    previousExpandedParentIndex = groupPosition;
}
```

NOTE THIS: **android.R.id.list**

and set **previousExpandedParentIndex = -1** as the class member

**3.**
go to your xml and change the id to this:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
```

**4.**
If you still get a crash, check that it doesn't happen in **findViewById** of step 2.

If so, it's because setContentView of your activity that extends extends ExpandableListActivity isn't set so do this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.expandable_list_view);
    **OR**
    ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView();
```

**I really HOPE I helped others to find out the solution in 1 page.**